# Passing the file name between OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have a wpf application and it gives no compiling errors but still doesn't work, what is wrong with my code?

Idea in short is described in the question title but it is supposed to prompt the user to open an excel file, then by pressing the other button should run the exportExcelToTxt method and give a save file dialog. The open file dialog works and when I press the other button it gives a savefile dialog but does not make a file where I choose it should.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnFileOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        var result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
        switch (result)
        {
            case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK:
                var file = fileDialog.FileName;
                TxtFile.Text = file;
                TxtFile.ToolTip = file;
                break;
            case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel:
            default:
                TxtFile.Text = null;
                TxtFile.ToolTip = null;
                break;
        }

    }

    private void convert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Configure save file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Save document
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
        }

    }
    static void exportExcelToTxt(string excelFilePath, string outputTxtPath)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<long>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<long>>();
        using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES", excelFilePath)))
        {
            excelConnection.Open();
            string firstSheet = getFirstSheetName(excelConnection);
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = excelConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", firstSheet);
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt); // Getting all the data in the sheet
                        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            List<long> toAdd = new List<long>();
                            string key = item[0] as string;
                            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                            {
                                toAdd.Add(Convert.ToInt64(item[i]));
                            }
                            values.Add(key, toAdd); // Associating all the "numbers" to the "Name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        StringBuilder toWriteToTxt = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<long>> item in values)
        {
            // Formatting the output
            toWriteToTxt.Append(string.Format("{0}:", item.Key));
            foreach (long val in item.Value.Distinct())
            {
                toWriteToTxt.AppendFormat("\t{0} * {1}\r\n", item.Value.Where(f => f == val).Count(),  // Amount of occurrencies of each number
                    val);
            }
        }
        // Writing the TXT
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputTxtPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.Write(toWriteToTxt.ToString());
            }
        }
    }


    static string getFirstSheetName(OleDbConnection excelConnection)
    {
        using (DataTable ExcelTables = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" }))
        {
            return ExcelTables.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, for reading/writing Excel files, I would recommend https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just for people who might end up here through google, I got the ISAM error and it was fixed by adding `\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"` in the extended properties part. Just the `\" .... \"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

This retrieves the selected file name from the dialog but you lose it immediately as `filename` is a local variable and you do not call the save/export method.

Add

```
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
    exportExcelToTxt(TxtFile.Text, filename);
}
```

Comment: I added the second option, now I get a compiling error "The name 'outputTxtPath' does not exist in the current content."

Comment: @Slyre - Could you add the code that calls the `exportExcelToTxt` method? When I know where you are calling it I can fix/update my answer.

Comment: de WeerdThat is the entire code, ctrl+a ctrl+v the whole thing.

Comment: @Slyre - in that case you are missing the call to the export method, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you! Now I just need to find out what is causing 'Could not find installable ISAM" OleDbException.